# Attribute error : Dataframe object has no attribute as_matrix

Tags: pandas, dataframe, h2o

When I am trying to convert pandas dataframe to h2o.H2OFrame, I am getting this error.

Comment: were u able to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can't track the issue given limited information in your question. You can try the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import h2o

# Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

# Conversion to h2o frame
hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
```

Comment: this is still giving same error. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398521/why-do-i-receive-attribute-error-when-i-try-to-convert-pandas-df-to-h2o-df